# How to print output of multiple JSch sessions in a loop?

Tags: java, session, ssh, jsch

Below code is intended to execute a command in multiple users of a particular server. This code is not connecting to each user, instead it is only running command in first user.

```
try {
    String users[] = {"sproln23", "sprsec23", "sproln52", "sprsec52"};

    for(String user: users) {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        System.out.println("Checking for user :" + user);
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, "server");
        session.setPassword("pass");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect(30000);

        Channel ch = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)ch).setCommand("whoami");
        ch.setOutputStream(System.out);
        ch.connect();
    }

} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Checking for user :sproln23
Checking for user :sprsec23
sproln23
```

**Expected Output**:

```
Checking for user :sproln23
sproln23
Checking for user :sprsec23
sprsec23
Checking for user :sproln52
sproln52
Checking for user :sprsec52
sprsec52
```

Comment: What do you expect the code to do? Do you want to run the commands in parallel? Or do you want to run the command for the first user, wait for it to complete and then carry on with the other user(s)?

Comment: It is fine by me if it runs in parallel as well. Although, my primary concern is to execute that command in every specified user.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have runs the commands in parallel (you do not wait for the commands to finish).

I'd say (though I did not test it) that once the first command finishes (asynchronously on the background, while you are processing other users), JSch closes the output stream. As you set `System.out` as the output stream, it effectively prevents your application from producing any more output.

Another possible problem is that, as you actually not wait for the commands to finish, your application (e.g. is a simple console application), can actually terminate before the commands finish. Though in that case you would at least "Checking for user" for each user.

You should try to only copy the output of JSch to `System.out`, instead of directly using `System.out`.

As the [official example for the "exec" channel shows](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html):

```
InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

channel.connect();

byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
while(true){
  while(in.available()>0){
    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if(i<0)break;
    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if(channel.isClosed()){
    if(in.available()>0) continue; 
    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }
  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
}
```

The above code solves both problems described above.